# Как поставить иконку в окне tkinter используя байтовый код изображения?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, icon

Возможно, я не совсем корректно написал заголовок.. Я используя tkinter и python 3+. Мне не хочется таскаться постоянно с файлом изображения для иконки, можно ли как-то избежать этого? Просмотрев несколько статей в инете нашел пару алгоритмов переводящих изображение в байтовый код, по вот беда - tkinter iconbitmap(), как я понял, не работает с байтами. Как можно ставить иконку на окно не используя файла изображения?